# Cannot attach the file 'C:...\DefaultConnection.mdf' as database 'DefaultConnection'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, mysql-connector, visual-studio-2019

i am trying to connect to mysql database and i have follow the correct steps for using it into ASP.NET, but when running the web app the following error apears:

> Cannot attach the file 'C:...\DefaultConnection.mdf' as database
>   'DefaultConnection'.

does anyone know why?
i have already tried adding a providerName tag unto providers tag that reference MySql.Data.MySqlClient thinking that possibly the problem is over there but dont think so, and the problem didnt get resolved.
code snippett:

```
        < add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;
          User Id=root;password='';
          database=datahub" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Believe the problem is over this line of code beacuse when i added it the problem was presented.

the link in which i got the reference of the connectionString was the following:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/589462/connectionplusstringplusforplusmysqlplusinplusasp

Comment: are you using entity framework? Also please put a link to the refrence you used to create this connection string.

Comment: It seems to try to attach an ms sql server data file, so my guess is that you left some kind of config entry in your config file.

Comment: @Train yes, i'm using Entity Framework, also yes, here is the link https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/589462/connectionplusstringplusforplusmysqlplusinplusasp

Comment: @Shadow Can you help me telling me what kind of config step or part do i left behind please?

Comment: Well, obviously something that references the default connection.

Comment: @Train My main problem is that i'm using MySQL as my database system, not SQL server, any suggestion for using MySQL, and also, which is better, SQL server or MySQL for ASP.NET

Comment: Sorry I missed that important point. Give me some time I'll try to look into it. The better choice depends on the app requirements.

Comment: Can you try changing the `name` attribute to `DefaultConnection`? Also how do you know that `127.0.0.1` is the correct Server address? You also never mentioned a password, does it have a password?

Comment: @Train, I have tried with the name DefaultConnection but it doesn’t add the data to my sql table, the server I’m sure that is that (127.0.0.1) because is written on phpmyadmin, also the password i am supposed to know that it doesn’t have a password so I put it as empty string (“”)

Comment: Sorry then, I'm at a loss. Try to look for some other examples online, maybe that can give you some more clues.

Comment: @Train the only thing I am finding to do is connect my asp.net web project to a MySQL database by the web.config, hope that helps to understand better the problem